# can't uninstall octave

Tags: software-uninstall, octave

I can run octave in the terminal by typing `octave` and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>,but I can't remove octave.

I type `sudo apt-get purge octave`,but it say

> Package 'octave' is not installed, so not removed.

I don't know why,can you guys help?

there is a question about how to completely uninstall software installed from source code,and there existed good answers to that problem.

But i also want to know why i can't uninstall by the command 
`sudo apt-get purge octave`.

I have read that question and i learned that i can do it by the command `make uninstall`,but i don't know where the octave uninstall makefile is.

I think the second answer here has solved my problem and can remove install software clean.

I installed `octave` from source code by typing `./configure && make && make install`.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed using `make install`, you can remove by `make uninstall`.

The `make clean` and `distclean` command only clean out the source directories, but
 they don't remove installed files. Assuming you built octave
from source using the defaults, you probably installed everything in
`/usr/local`, so you can probably remove everything with the following command:

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/octave-****
$ rm -rf /usr/local/share/octave/****
$ rm -rf /usr/local/lib/octave-****
$ rm -rf /usr/local/libexec/octave/****
```

[Source](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/uninstalling-octave-td1625823.html)

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is a package system, meanwhile you building and installing Octave from source.

You can install octave with `apt-get install octave` or make a deb package from sources following this [tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).

If you want to uninstall Octave in your situation, go to source directory and run `make uninstall` from there.